# Power set of $A_1=\{\emptyset\}$ set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume that $A_1=\{\emptyset\}$ and $A_{n+1}=\mathcal{P}(A_n)\backslash\{\emptyset\}$ with $\mathcal{P}(A_n)$ power set. I have to find the $A_2$, $A_3$ and $A_4$ sets.

So $A_2=\mathcal{P}(A_1)\backslash\{\emptyset\}=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\backslash\{\emptyset\}$ and that means that $A_2=\{\emptyset\}$ or $A_2=\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ or something else?

Comment: $\emptyset\neq \{\emptyset\}$ and this is further different than $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ and so on.   The "depth" is important here.

Comment: So what is the correct answer to $A_2$ ? @JMoravitz

Comment: That being said, you correctly found $A_2 = \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\setminus \{\emptyset\}$.  You should know how $\{a,b\}\setminus \{a\}$ works and results in $\{b\}$.  Now, replace $a$ by $\emptyset$ and replace $b$ by $\{\emptyset\}$, remembering that these are different.

Comment: Your set contains one element. The power set of a set containing one element contains $2^1=2$ elements. The power set of a set always contains both the empty set and  the set itself. So there are no other elements in the power set, meaning it must be $\{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}$.

Comment: @MPW It is confusing to me what you mean by "it" in this context.  The question doesn't seem to be what the power set of $\{\emptyset\}$ is, but rather what $A_2$ is, i.e. the set of non-trivial subsets of $A_1$, while $A_3$ is the set of non-trivial subsets of $A_2$ and so on...

Comment: Yes, I was just talking about the power set of $A_1$, @JMoravitz

Comment: $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have correctly identified $P(A_1)$ now in order to calculate
$$\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\setminus\{\emptyset\}$$
consider the elements of each set. The first set has elements $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$. Now the second set only has the element $\emptyset$. Hence their set difference which contains elements unique to the first set only has the element $\{\emptyset\}$. Thus we have
$$A_2=\{\{\emptyset\}\}$$
In fact, repeating this process, gives
$$A_n=\overbrace{\{\{\dots\{\emptyset\}\dots\}\}}^{2n\text{ braces}}$$

Comment: And that means that $A_3=\mathcal{P}(A_2)\backslash\{\emptyset\}=\{\emptyset,\{\{\emptyset\}\}\}\backslash\{\emptyset\}=\{\{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ ?

Comment: @SotirisZ. Yes you are correct.